# Find and replace with AWK command

Tags: macos, unix, awk, gsub, gawk

I have a file called sso_med.txt like

```
197: insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date,last_updated_by) values ('502683504',15,current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160'); 
198: insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date,last_updated_by) values ('502683504',16,current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160'); 
199: insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date,last_updated_by) values ('502689031',15,current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');
```

But I want to make it like

```
insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date,last_updated_by) values ('502683504',15,current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160'); 
insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date,last_updated_by) values ('502683504',16,current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160'); 
insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date,last_updated_by) values ('502689031',15,current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');
```

I am trying the awk command

```
awk '{gsub(/^\d+:\s/,""); print}' sso_med.txt
```

But its not working.Any idea what I am doing wrong in Regex

Comment: `\d` is not recognized. Replace it with `[0-9]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
awk '{gsub(/^[0-9]+: /,"")}1' file
```

Comment: Downvoted for lack of explanation. Please note what asker did right/wrong in their expression compared to yours.

Answer (score 0):

try also sed version:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]*: //'  Input_file
```

substituting the starting digits from 0 to 9 and then : to space with NULL and print the rest.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid removing similar patterns elsewhere in the string, use `sub`, which just replaces the first instance of the pattern:

```
# explanation of regex: "^"=line starts with pattern, "[0-9]+"=multiple numbers, ": "=colon and single space
awk '{sub(/^[0-9]+: /, "", $0); print $0}'
```

Example:

```
$ echo '197: insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date,last_updated_by) values ('502683504',15,current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');' | awk '{sub(/^[0-9]+: /, "", $0); print $0}'
```

Result:

```
insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date,last_updated_by) values (502683504,15,current_date, 502264160, current_date, 502264160);
```